# Lenovo Z50-70: possible upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, ssd

I have a Lenovo Z50 laptop and I play games like NFS and DOOM. I also run some simulations using Octave.

CPU: Core i7-4500

RAM: 8GB

HDD: 1TB 5400rpm

I am looking for upgrading my laptop with reasonable price. the first option that comes to my mind is to increase ram to 16GB or install an SSD or replace HDD with a faster one. the later is not a good idea because of heat and power consumption.
 Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although my personal preference is to remove the DVD drive, replace it with a caddy, and drop an SSD into that caddy (possibly with caching involved), a simpler, somewhat slower option that allows you to retain your DVD drive is to replace your HDD with an SHDD. I recommend the **[Seagate - 1TB Internal Serial ATA III/Serial ATA II Solid State Hybrid Drive for Laptops](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/seagate-1tb-internal-serial-ata-iii-serial-ata-ii-solid-state-hybrid-drive-for-laptops-multi/8808633.p?id=1218897640424&ref=199&loc=8BacdVP0GFs&acampID=1&siteID=8BacdVP0GFs-fHEa_iB9MXI.aQygONjP5w)**. This drive has 1Tb of slow storage, backed up with 8Gb of MLC flash, which it uses to automagically cache the rest of the drive according to how you use it. Think of the performance as being somewhere between your standard HDD and SSDs.

Comment: I think if I drop the HDD to the caddy and have an SSD as main storage can improve the performance. I have read a couple of review on that combination. but I am not sure about its performance because of heat and maybe power consumption. what I have in my mind is to install a 240GB SSD and have 1TB HDD installed in a caddy.

Comment: Just my two cents - keep the HDD in its normal space and put the SSD in the caddy. SSDs are much more heat and vibration tolerant than HDDs.